# Let $M$ be an $R$-module. Then $M$ is cyclic $R$-module iff there is a left ideal $A$ in $R$ st. $M$ isomorphic to $R/A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals

> Let $M$ be an $R$-module. Then $M$ is cyclic $R$-module if and only if there is a left ideal $A$ in $R$ such that $M$ isomorphic to $R/A$.

I am not sure why this is true. One proof of this says that $R/A = \langle 1+A \rangle$, but I am not sure why this would be true; indeed, given the addition in $R/A$, would the generating not consist only of integer multiples of $1$? Am I not understanding this correctly?

Comment: Is it necessary that $A$ is a two-sided ideal of $R$ to define $R/A$ as a left $R$-module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element $1 + A$ generates $R/A$ as an $R$-module. Indeed, for any $r + A \in R/A$,  we have
$$
r + A = (r\cdot 1) + A = r(1 + A),
$$
by how scalar multiplication on the quotient module is defined. Thus, $R/A$ is clearly a cyclic module.

The integers are not involved here; this is not a module over $\mathbb{Z}$, but rather over a general ring $R$, which may be causing the confusion.

Now,  note that this proves the backwards direction; if $M$ is isomorphic to $R/A$, then it is cyclic, since $R/A$ is cyclic. For the forwards direction, suppose $M$ is cyclic, generated by $x \in M$ (so $M = \langle x \rangle$). Consider the map $x \mapsto 1_R + A$, where $A$ is a certain ideal (for this, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_module).

Comment: For the second part, I would define a map $R \to M$ by sending $1$ to a generator of $M$. This way you avoid figuring out what the ideal is before defining the map